# How to run a class which runs multiple Selenium classes?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, testng

I have a test which I would like to know if it's possible to run with one click. What I mean is I have a class which runs e other classes and another one which runs one (I am doing research right now, so the tests ran are quite basic. so I have the class

```
package testNGresearch;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import multipleTest.Loginer;

public class AllLoginTestsNG extends OneClickTest{

    public static WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl = "https://9gag.com/";
    @BeforeTest
    public void openBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void GetUrl() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        Loginer.login(driver);
    }
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void clickSignUp() {
        Loginer1.signUp(driver);
    }
    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void cancelSignUp() {
        Loginer2.cancelSignUp(driver);
        driver.close();
    }
    @Test(priority=4)
    public void navigationTests() throws InterruptedException {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        NavigationTestNG.navigation(driver);
    }
}
```

and then another one (seperate file)

```
package testNGresearch;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Loginer extends AllLoginTestsNG{


    @Test
    public void login() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/button[2]/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"jsid-login-button\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-email-name\"]")).sendKeys("someuser");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-email-password\"]")).sendKeys("somepass");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-email\"]/div[3]/input")).click();
    }
}
```

Then the second one which is ran by the AllLogin class

```
package testNGresearch;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Loginer1 extends AllLoginTestsNG {

    @Test
    public static void signUp(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"jsid-signup-button\"]")).click();
    }

}
```

Now I have a class AllNavigation

```
package testNGresearch;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AllNavigationTestsNG extends AllLoginTestsNG {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl = "https://9gag.com/";
    @BeforeTest
    public void openBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void startNavigating (WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        NavigationTestNG.navigation(driver);
    }
}
```

Which runs

```
package testNGresearch;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NavigationTestNG extends AllNavigationTestsNG {

    @Test (priority = 1)
    public static void navigation(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/button[2]/span")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"top-nav\"]/div/a")).click();
    }
}
```

So the question is - Is it possible to create a class which runs the AllLogin class and the AllNavigationTestNG class (which makes them run one after another)
I created a OneClickTest class which throws errors

```
package testNGresearch;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class OneClickTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver;
        AllLoginTestsNG.allLogin(driver);
        AllNavigationTestsNG.anotherLogin(driver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing it this way. You can create a Browser Driver class which implements your driver related wrappers. Then, you can create your test classes and execute them via testng.xml directly by a click.

Comment: The idea is to have a class which is a one-click-test which is ran before the project is launched and other classes which are for maintenance and when needed to run for example only login test or only upload test etc. So if there is a problem with the login then I don't have to run the whole suite, but just the login test.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I am suggesting. Doable with testng.xml itself. You don't need extra efforts. Lemme post it for you.

Comment: You can use Page Object Model Scenario for same, where you can access method wherever it meant. It can easily utilize with TestNg desired annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite"  parallel="tests" verbose="1">
    <test name="testNGresearch" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.testNGresearch.AllNavigationTestsNG " />
            <class name="com.testNGresearch.AllLoginTestsNG" />
        </classes>
    </test> 
    <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

1. Make sure you have correct package names when specifying classes under test.
2. Make your test such that - lets say login - completely login fucntionality into one test.
3. Put all your page objects into a separate class and you can make them static.
4. Have only one class to take care of Webdriver related functions.

Note - Like `login()` inside `Loginer` class is not a good way as you are depending on some other function to take you to this screen. You should develop test as independent as they can be and put assertions pertaining to one inside itself.
Let me know if any questions.

For your refernce,

```
package testNGresearch;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import multipleTest.Loginer;

public class AllLoginTestsNG{

    public static WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl = "https://9gag.com/";
    @BeforeTest
    public void openBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void GetUrl() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        Thread.sleep(1500);
     }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void cancelSignUp() {
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: As I am new to this I don't know how to create the xml file. If you could tell me how and where to create it or if you have a useful link where I can read on how to do that I will be grateful.

Comment: Sure.  First you create only one test class with one test method init like you are doing above. Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377239/how-to-create-testng-xml-using-eclipse) to create testing.xml. Keep me posted if you face any issues.

Comment: I created an xml successfully and added the code that you wrote and it gives me the error: 
    Cannot find class in classpath: com.testNGresearch.AllNavigationTestsNG

Comment: Then I used the one which was created (which when I ran I just got two browser windows pop up but nothing else happened) and it tells me this: Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [signUp] with [interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver].

Comment: I modified your class a bit. Can you try putting only this one in testng.xml and see ? Please make sure to put the class name with correct package

Comment: I changed the names and got an error again, but I found out how to fix it and now everything is working perfectly. Thank you so much! I just have one question - when I run the suite it runs both tests at the same time and I was wondering if there is a way to make it so it runs them one at a time?

Comment: Glad, I could help. Try removing parallel from testng.xml. Thank you for accepting it as answer. Please upvote as well. If any issues, I will try to take a look later mate. Signing off for now.

Comment: I removed the parallel from test.xml and it still opens two browsers.
I guess this is just because my tests are written this way, so if I fix the way they are written it will execute the way I want it to.

Comment: Can you please try updating testng.xml to `parallel="methods", thread-count="1"`. Please remove `parallel="tests"`

Comment: Now it opens 2 browsers, but it runs the test on first one and after that it runs the second one. I will have a look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by executing TestNG.XML suite file,

**This is sample code reference :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite"  parallel="tests" verbose="1">
    <test name="My Account Test" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="myAccount.login" />
            <class name="myAccount.registration" />
            <class name="myAccount.forgotPassword" />
            <class name="myAccount.signOut" />
        </classes>
    </test> 
    <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Here Login script will call first, after that Registration and so on in defined Order. By this way you can have effective communication to calling multiple class with Single Click of TestNG.XML suite file.